# DYLD error when starting up mongodb

Tags: macos, mongodb, dyld

I installed mongo with:

```
brew install mongodb
```

I created the data directory:

```
/data/dir
```

i included `mongod` the path (`which mongod --> /opt/local/bin/mongod`):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin/mongod
```

I tried to run `mongod`:

```
mongod
```

And got this response:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitERKSsPKNS_10RE_OptionsE
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/mongod
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libpcrecpp.0.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitERKSsPKNS_10RE_OptionsE
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/mongod
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libpcrecpp.0.dylib
```

What is this error all about? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I had set the path to the wrong directory

Brew installs packages into `/usr/local/bin` which is where there resides a symlink `mongod@ -> homebrew's cellar`

so, instead, I ran `/usr/local/bin/mongod` and then it started fine.